# Sampling raster values into attribute table of polyline layer

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, average

I have several raster layers and one vector polyline layer. I'd like to sample the rasters into the attribute table of the vector layer. Because the lines span multiple raster cells, this can be done by averaging raster values along line segments.

Is there a way to neatly do this?

Right now I'm using QGIS.

Comment: Interesting question, but please edit your post to include more detail.  For example, you use the plural word "columns", which implies that multiple values would be averaged.  If so, what is getting averaged: each of the multiple raster layer?  Or maybe you meant to use a singular "column", wherein all rasters are to be averaged?  Next, over what portion of the line will the averaging occur: the entire line, between each line segment, between each line vertex, or raster cell?  Including a picture (even hand-drawn) would be a big help!

Comment: Yes thanks for the prompt to clarify. By "columns" I meant columns of the attribute table. I want to sample rasters into attributes of the vector layer.

Comment: Sorry, but your response doesn't answer my questions.  If you want assistance, you're going to have to make a better effort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Densify by interval to add more vertices to your lines (optional)
2. Drape to extract the raster values to each lines vertices z value
3. Extract z values to add these as an attribute, with Summaries to calculate = mean
4. Repeat for each raster. For example manually or using pyqgis

[image]

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a (vector) grid using squareas (polygons) with the same CRS, extent and cell size as your raster. So cells should fit perfectly with raster pixels.
2. Use Select by location to select the cells intersecting the lines. Delete all other cells.
3. Get the raster value for each of the remaining cells and create a new attribute `elevation`. Use this expression: `raster_value( 'raster',1, centroid($geometry))` where `raster` is the name of the raster layer and `1` the no. of the band.
4. On the line layer reate the mean value from all `elevation` values of the cells that intersect the line. Use this expression: `array_mean (overlay_intersects( 'grid', elevation))`, where `grid` is the name of the grid layer.

*Line (blue) and grid (red outline) with the corresponding elevation values from the raster. The blue label `808.4` is dynamically created as label with the expression from above as you can see in the yellow highlighted part:*

[image]